# ¿Como solucionar este problema al insertar datos en cascada en hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

quisiera saber como resolver el siguiente error al insertar datos `save()` a la `BD` en `cascada` con Hibernate, ademas de ello agregue las anotaciones `(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` en las clases relacionadas que tiene `Alumno`

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate.contacto' doesn't existCaused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate.contacto' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
```

Aqui se encuentra mi metodo insertar

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

        //1. Creamos el objeto Domicilio
        Domicilio domicilio = new Domicilio();
        domicilio.setCalle("Allende");
        domicilio.setNoExterno("115");
        domicilio.setNoInterno("A-101");
        domicilio.setVersion(0);
        domicilio.setDeleted(0);

        //2. Creamos el objeto Contacto
        Contacto contacto = new Contacto();
        contacto.setTelefono("557171189");
        contacto.setEmail1("contacto@email.com");
        contacto.setVersion(0);
        contacto.setDeleted(0);

        //3. Creamos el objeto Alumno
        //e insertamos sus valores requeridos de contacto y domicilio
        Alumno alumno = new Alumno();
        alumno.setNombre("Martha");
        alumno.setApellidoPaterno("Martinez");
        alumno.setApellidoMaterno("Garcia");
        alumno.setDomicilio(domicilio);//Es un objeto no persistente
        alumno.setContacto(contacto);//Es un objeto no persistente
        alumno.setVersion(0);
        alumno.setDeleted(0);

        //Iniciamos la transacción y guardamos la información

        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(alumno);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }

        //Imprimimos el objeto insertado
        System.out.println("Alumno insertado: "+alumno);
    }
```

Mi archivo hibernate.cfg.xml con las clases mapeadas

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mysql</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Alumno"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Asignacion"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Contacto"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Curso"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Domicilio"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Empleado"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Instructor"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Pago"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Rol"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Sucursal"/>
        <mapping class="com.ejemplo.hibernate.model.Usuario"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

La clase Alumno

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alumno")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumno.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Alumno a")})
public class Alumno implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_alumno")
    private Integer idAlumno;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "apellido_paterno")
    private String apellidoPaterno;

    @Column(name = "apellido_materno")
    private String apellidoMaterno;

    @Column(name = "genero")
    private String genero;

    @Column(name = "fecha_nacimiento")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaNacimiento;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "deleted")
    private int deleted;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alumno")
    private List<Asignacion> asignacionList;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_contacto", referencedColumnName = "id_contacto")
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Contacto contacto;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_domicilio", referencedColumnName = "id_domicilio")
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Domicilio domicilio;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario", referencedColumnName = "id_usuario")
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario usuario;

    public Alumno() {
    }

    public Alumno(Integer idAlumno) {
        this.idAlumno = idAlumno;
    }

    public Alumno(Integer idAlumno, String nombre, String apellidoPaterno, int version, int deleted) {
        this.idAlumno = idAlumno;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno;
        this.version = version;
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public Integer getIdAlumno() {
        return idAlumno;
    }

    public void setIdAlumno(Integer idAlumno) {
        this.idAlumno = idAlumno;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidoPaterno() {
        return apellidoPaterno;
    }

    public void setApellidoPaterno(String apellidoPaterno) {
        this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno;
    }

    public String getApellidoMaterno() {
        return apellidoMaterno;
    }

    public void setApellidoMaterno(String apellidoMaterno) {
        this.apellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public int getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(int deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public List<Asignacion> getAsignacionList() {
        return asignacionList;
    }

    public void setAsignacionList(List<Asignacion> asignacionList) {
        this.asignacionList = asignacionList;
    }

    public Contacto getContacto() {
        return contacto;
    }

    public void setContacto(Contacto contacto) {
        this.contacto = contacto;
    }

    public Domicilio getDomicilio() {
        return domicilio;
    }

    public void setDomicilio(Domicilio domicilio) {
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idAlumno != null ? idAlumno.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Alumno)) {
            return false;
        }
        Alumno other = (Alumno) object;
        if ((this.idAlumno == null && other.idAlumno != null)
                || (this.idAlumno != null && !this.idAlumno.equals(other.idAlumno))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno{" + "idAlumno=" + idAlumno + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellidoPaterno=" + apellidoPaterno
                + ", apellidoMaterno=" + apellidoMaterno + ", genero=" + genero + ", fechaNacimiento=" + fechaNacimiento
                + ", version=" + version + ", deleted=" + deleted + ", contacto=" + contacto + ", domicilio="
                + domicilio + ", usuario=" + usuario + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Si les quito la anotación de (cascade=CascadeType.ALL) me devuelve el error diciendo lo siguiente  ERROR: Table 'hibernate.alumno' doesn't exist

Comment: Es el mismo error que te está dando ahora. No creo que sea por la inserción en cascada, creo que es por la relación con contacto. Cuando lo soluciones supongo que lo mismo te pasará con domicilio y usuario

Comment: Lograste resolver el problema

Comment: Vi ejemplos pero no logré realizar ese ejercicio

Answer (score 0):

Parece que es un problema de construcción de la base de datos que aún no tiene las tablas creadas. Con hibernate tienes la opción de que se ejecuten todos los DDL correspondientes si añades en la configuración:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

Si no lo quieres dejar en manos de hibernate tambien puedes crear tu propio script de inicializacion:

Creas un fichero *ddl.sql* como recurso con la inicialización de la base de datos (incluido el create schema o create database si fuera necesario) y luego en tu fichero de configuracion de hibernate:

```
<session-factory>
    ...
    <property name="hbm2ddl.import_files">ddl.sql</property>
    ...
</session-factory>
```

Es importante que NO uses root como usuario:

```
CREATE DATABASE tu_base_de_datos;
CREATE USER 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_contrasena';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON tu_base_de_datos.* TO 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: La base de datos y las tablas ya estan creadas

Comment: es posible que las hayas creado en otro esquema? prueba a ejecutarlo como te digo y verifica si crea las tablas correctamente. Si es así es que estas usando un el esquema por defecto del usuario 'root'. Es importante que utilices otro usuario, prueba a crear uno con tu base de datos por defecto y realiza la conexión con el en la configuracion de hibernate.